# state object is 'undefined' and so its properties, while received from an item in localStorage and throws error. auto resolve after 2 second! why?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am making 2 types of user into my app.

- Normal User
- Specific User (ones with some specific criteria according to scope of app, company's requirement).

I have created 6 paired requests from axios to API Server

```
first 3 - (
 - Login_UserA
 - Register_UserA
 - Current_UserA
)

other 3 - (

 - Login_UserB
 - Register_UserB
 - Current_UserB
)
```

I created 2 slices to handle the account of each of the users named -

- userA_accountSlice.ts
- userB_accountSlice.ts

(both have differnet type interfaces User_TypeA.ts , and User_TypeB.ts)

```
interface UserAccountState {
 appUser : AppUser | null;
 status : string;
};

export const initialState : UserAccountState = {
 appUser_A : null,
 status : 'idle',
};


export const loginUserAsync = createAsyncThunk<AppUser_TypeA, FieldValues>( 
'userAccount/loginUserA',
async ( data, thunkAPI ) => {
try {
 const userA_DTO = await agent.Account.loginUser_A(data);
 const { basket , ...loginData } = userA_DTO;
 browserStorage.insert('userA', loginData); // it is same as localStorage.setItem(just created a utility out of it-- please ignore browserstorage, same as localstorage)
 return loginData;
} catch ( error : any ) {
 return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error : error.data });
}});


export const fetchCurrentUser_A = createAsyncThunk<AppUser_TypeA, void, {state : RootState}>(
 'userAccount/fetchCurrentUserA',
async ( _ , thunkAPI ) => {
thunkAPI.dispatch(setUser_A(JSON.parse(browserStorage.retrive('userA')!))); // same as localStorage.getItem()
try {
 const userA_DTO = await agent.Account.currentUser_A();
 browserStorage.insert('user', userA_DTO);

 return userA_DTO;
} catch (error : any ) {
 return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error : error.data });
}}, { condition : () => { if (!browserStorage.retrive('userA')) return false; }
});

export const userA_AccountSlice = createSlice({
 name : 'userAccount_A',
 initialState,
 reducers : {
  setUser_A : ( state, action ) => {
   state.appUser_A = action.payload;
  },
   
  // sign-out (logout) user
  signOutUser_A : ( state ) => {
  try {
   state.appUser_A = null;
   browserStorage.erase('userA');
   router.navigate('/login');
  } catch (error : any) {
    console.log(error, 'problem while signing-out:(user), try again!')
  }},
 },
 extraReducers : ( builder => {

  // register user A- (when pending)
  builder.addCase(registerUserA.pending, (state) => {
   state.status = 'pendingRegisterUserA';
  });
       
  // register user - (when fulfiiled)
  builder.addCase(registerUserA.fulfilled, ( state, action ) => {
   state.appUser_A = action.payload;
   router.navigate('/login');
   state.status = 'idle'; 
  });
     
  // register user -(when rejected)
  builder.addCase(registerUserA.rejected, (state) => {
   state.status = 'idle';
  });

  // login user - (when rejected)
  builder.addCase(loginUserA.rejected, (state, action) => {
   state.status = 'idle';
  });

  // fetch current-user - (when rejected)
  builder.addCase(fetchCurrentUserAsync.rejected, (state, action) => {
   state.appUser_A = null;
   router.navigate('/login');
  });

  // login user & fetch current-user - (when fulfilled)
  builder.addMatcher(isAnyOf(loginUserA.fulfilled, fetchCurrentUserA.fulfilled),  ( state, action ) => {
   state.appUser_A = action.payload;
   router.navigate('/');
  });
 })
});

export const { setUser_A, signOutUser_A } = userA_AccountSlice.actions;
```

Similarly, the accountSlice for 'User-B' of the application is named - **userB_AccountSlice.ts**

```
 interface UserAccountState {
     appUser_B : AppUserType_B | null;
     status : string;
    };
    
    export const initialState : UserAccountState = {
     appUser_B : null,
     status : 'idle',
    };
    
  
    export const loginUserAsync_B = createAsyncThunk<AppUser_TypeB, FieldValues>( 
    'userAccount/loginUserB',
    async ( data, thunkAPI ) => {
    try {
     const userB_DTO = await agent.Account.loginUser_B(data);
     const { books, ...loginData } = userB_DTO;
     browserStorage.insert('userB', loginData); // it is same as localStorage.setItem(just created a utility out of it-- please ignore browserstorage, same as localstorage)
     return loginData;
    } catch ( error : any ) {
     return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error : error.data });
    }});
    
 
    export const fetchCurrentUser_B = createAsyncThunk<AppUser_TypeB, void, {state : RootState}>(
     'userAccount/fetchCurrentUserB',
    async ( _ , thunkAPI ) => {
    thunkAPI.dispatch(setUser_B(JSON.parse(browserStorage.retrive('userB')!))); // same as localStorage.getItem()
    try {
     const userA_DTO = await agent.Account.currentUser_B();
     browserStorage.insert('userB', userB_DTO);
 
     return userA_DTO;
    } catch (error : any ) {
     return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue({ error : error.data });
    }}, { condition : () => { if (!browserStorage.retrive('userB')) return false; }
    });
    
    export const userB_AccountSlice = createSlice({
     name : 'userAccount_B',
     initialState,
     reducers : {
      setUser_B : ( state, action ) => {
       state.appUser_B = action.payload;
      },
       
      // sign-out (logout) user
      signOutUser_B : ( state ) => {
      try {
       state.appUser_B = null;
       browserStorage.erase('userB');
       router.navigate('/login');
      } catch (error : any) {
        console.log(error, 'problem while signing-out:(user), try again!')
      }},
     },
     extraReducers : ( builder => {
    
      // register user B- (when pending)
      builder.addCase(registerUserB.pending, (state) => {
       state.status = 'pendingRegisterUserB';
      });
           
      // register user - (when fulfiiled)
      builder.addCase(registerUserB.fulfilled, ( state, action ) => {
       state.appUser_B = action.payload;
       router.navigate('/login');
       state.status = 'idle'; 
      });
         
      // register user -(when rejected)
      builder.addCase(registerUserB.rejected, (state) => {
       state.status = 'idle';
      });
    
      // login user - (when rejected)
      builder.addCase(loginUserB.rejected, (state, action) => {
       state.status = 'idle';
      });
    
      // fetch current-user - (when rejected)
      builder.addCase(fetchCurrentUserB.rejected, (state, action) => {
       state.appUser_B = null;
       router.navigate('/login');
      });
    
      // login user & fetch current-user - (when fulfilled)
      builder.addMatcher(isAnyOf(loginUserB.fulfilled, fetchCurrentUserB.fulfilled),  ( state, action ) => {
       state.appUser_B = action.payload;
       router.navigate('/');
      });
     })
    });
    
    export const { setUser_B, signOutUser_B } = userB_AccountSlice.actions;
```

I am able to login userA, and userB correctly. whilst login, I am setting 'userA' or 'userB', depending upon who logs in, to the localStorage.
The 'userA' , and 'userB' contains a 'token', which is a property in UserA which I have setUserA, or SetUserB (as mentioned above), so that I could intercept it to the axios requests going to API Server, and append it to **`Bearer ${token}`** to my **Authorization** Header. Everything is working fine till now.

- I also used **RequireAuth.tsx** component, which either returns the  if (no user is present in **localStorage**) else returns  if either user is present.
  RequireAuth.tsx

  export default function RequireAuth () {

  ```
   // 1. [browser localStorage] 
   const appUser_A = JSON.parse(browserStorage.retrive('userA')!); 
   const appUser_B= JSON.parse(browserStorage.retrive('userB')!); 

   // 2. react-router-dom
   const location = useLocation();

   if (!appUser_A && !appUser_B) {
    return <Navigate to = {'login'} state = {{ from : location }} />
   }

   return <Outlet /> };
  ```

I am calling **fetchCurrentUser_A** and **fetchCurrentUser_B** inside different useCallBacks (async versions), and useEffects into my App.tsx file - (as under)

```
function App() {

// using(s)
// 1. local-state
const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

// 2. react-context
const { theme, setAppBackground, appBackground } = useThemeContext();
// 3. redux
const { appUser_A } = useAppSelector(state => state.userA_Account);
const { appUser_B } = useAppSelector (state => state.userB_Account);
const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

const InitializeAppWithUser_A = useCallback(async () => {
try {
await dispatch(fetchCurrentUser_A()); 
} catch (error : any ) {
 console.log(error);
}}, [dispatch]);

const InitializeAppWithUser_B = useCallback(async () => {
try {
await dispatch(fetchCurrentUser_B()); 
} catch (error : any) { 
 console.log(error); 
}}, [dispatch]);

useEffect(() => {
 InitializeAppWithUserA().then(() => setLoading(false));
 InitializeAppWithUserB().then(() => setLoading(false));
}, [InitializeAppWithUserA, InitializeAppWithUserB]);


if (loading) return <AppLoadingComponent type={'animated'} />

return (
  <Fragment>

    <ThemeProvider theme = {theme} >
      <CssBaseline />

    {(appUser_A || appUser_B) && <Header />}  

    {(appUser_A || appUser_B) && <MessageBox />}

    <Suspense fallback = {<AppLoadingComponent
                           type = {'text'}
                           message = {'Please wait. Loading ...'} />} >
      <Outlet />
    </Suspense>
    </ThemeProvider>

  </Fragment>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So, this is the above code I have provided to you.
**CASE 1)** Now, everything is working fine, when User A logs in, the userA is set to localStorage, and state as well for UserA, and then that state for UserA, is used to update the userMenu, profile page etc.

**CASE 2)** But, when user logs in as User_B, then indeed 'userB' gets stored inside of the localStorage, but before updating the state for userB, I get an error message for around - (2 - 3 seconds),
error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
    at Object.MaxCharactors (charactorTweaker.tsx:44:1)
    at UserMenu (UserMenu.tsx:159:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
MaxCharactors @ charactorTweaker.tsx:44
UserMenu @ UserMenu.tsx:159
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25738
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
charactorTweaker.tsx:44 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
    at Object.MaxCharactors (charactorTweaker.tsx:44:1)
    at UserMenu (UserMenu.tsx:159:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
MaxCharactors @ charactorTweaker.tsx:44
UserMenu @ UserMenu.tsx:159
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25750
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <UserMenu> component:

    at UserMenu (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:6360:82)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:8970:66
    at Toolbar (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:31864:82)
    at div
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:8970:66
    at Container (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:35708:19)
    at header
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:8970:66
    at Paper (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:28815:82)
    at http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:8970:66
    at AppBar (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:15206:83)
```

from this error - I have concluded that my state object for userB is undefined for like 2-3 seconds because, the component not mounted properly, I guess, but after 2-3 seconds, the state object for 'userB' takes the values from 'userB' key stored inside of localStorage and get updated, ultimately, redirecting me to the home page, with all the userB details just fine.

But, this **2 second error display message**, into console and UI as well, is *very annoying* for the end users of the application.

How could I change my above code, either inside of **"userAccountA_Slice.ts** or **'userAccountB_Slice.ts** or anywhere maybe **App.tsx**
or
**RequireAuth.tsx**,
or the way I am utilizing 'userA's property or user'B's properties inside of my **UserMenu.tsx** file,
or any **profile related component**, which depends directly upon the data returned from **fetchCurrentUser()** method , such that the user does not remain undefined ???

Because, I know, *once I handle the 'userA' or 'userB' being undefined*, *not to show as undefined* as soon as the localStorage content updates the state object for 'UserA' (when user A login), or 'userB' when User_B login,

then I am sure, the undefined error (for 2-3 seconds) should go away.But, How could I solve this issue?

And yes I am updating the **UserMenu.tsx** items by checking the following -

```
const {appUser_TypeA} = useAppSelector(state= > state.userA_Account);
const {appUser_TypeB} = useAppSelector(state => state.userB_Account);

const UserArray = [
function UserName () : string {
switch(true) {
 case appUser_TypeA && !appUser_TypeB : return appUser_TypeA.displayName; // this is point of error
case !appUser_TypeA && appUser_TypeB : return appUser_TypeB.someproperty; 
default : return '';
} }];

return (
<Typography>{UserArray[0]()}</Typography>
)}
```

Why I am getting this **undefined error**? is it because of **parsing undefined value from JSON.parse** ? returning undefined?
if yes, at which point should I resolve it, and how should I resolve it, as it is very annoying during application login for the end-users.

Please provide suggestions, I respect all of your suggestions
Thank You All : )

Comment: You need to provide I think your file `charactorTweaker.tsx` to ease the help

Comment: Hello Wandrille, the charactorTweaker, is a utility file, which is effectively is a function, that returns the bold text only.  let Max_Length : number = 0;
const MaxCharactors = (sentence : string, type : string) => {
switch(type) {
    case 'userName' : Max_Length = 10;
    break;
    default : Max_Length = 250;
}

return sentence > sentence.substring( 0, Max_Length) ? `${sentence.substring(0, Max_Length)}...` : sentence ;
};

Comment: This is the content of the charactortweaker file

Comment: How do you call the charactorTweaker.tsx from the UserMenu.tsx file? Could be of more help if you display this part of the code from the UserMenu.tsx file